# Klein-Gordon particles and Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, antimatter

The solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation for free particles are $e^{-iE_p t+i\vec{p}.\vec{x}}$ and $e^{iE_p t+i\vec{p}.\vec{x}}$ for energy eigenvalues of $E=E_p$ and $E=-E_p$ respectively. The charge denstiy $\rho=\frac{ie}{2m}[\psi^*\partial_t\psi-\psi\partial _t\psi^*]$ is postive for positive energy and negative for negative energy. For Klein-Gordon particles, particles are positively charged and anti-particles are negatively charged.

On the other hand, the Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation says that the negative energy particle moving backward in time is mathematically equivalent to positive energy anti-particle moving forward in time.

**Question**

How can anti-particle have positive energy? As for positive energy, charge density $\rho$ is positive, how it can represent negatively charged antiparticle?

Comment: physics stack exchange prefers (requires?) that you ask only one question per question. And these questions are pretty independent. I'd recommend removing one.

Comment: Okay, I have revomed the second question.